Construct a topology $T$ on $X=(-\infty,0]$, such that $X$ is compact?

Construct a topology $T$ on $X=(-\infty,0]$, which differ from trivial topology and discrete topology, such that $X$ is compact?


What have you tried?

i tried. but it is quite hard for me

Hint: think of the word finite in the definition of compactness

sorry but can you make it clear?

Tell us what you tried.

i try using the continuity. is it useful?

"Using the continuity" is meaningless right now.  Using continuity could mean finding a continuous bijection from the usual $(-\infty, 0]$ to a compact space, and then doing something to define $T$, but I can't be sure such steps make sense to you without extensive commentary.

do you have another answer? can y'all give me hints?

Any space with a finite topology is compact, because any open cover is necessarily finite. So, it suffices to find a finite topology for your space $X = (-\infty, 0]$.
Recall that a topology on $X$ must include $\emptyset, X$, and be closed to finite intersections and arbitrary unions.
Consider then something simple, like $\mathcal{T} = \{ \emptyset, X, (-\infty, -1], (-1, 0] \}$. You can verify that $\mathcal{T}$ is closed to finite intersections, because the only two nontrivial open sets are disjoint (this also means that the space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is disconnected). And, the union of those sets is equal to the entire space, so $\mathcal{T}$ is closed to arbitrary unions.

thank you. but how can we see its compactness?

@hnuyq Any open cover of $X$ is necessarily finite. So it trivially follows that every open cover has a finite subcover (just take the cover itself).
